# Can you 'mix and match' between buttons in a VBScript MsgBox?

Tags: windows, vba, vbscript

I'm learning to code in VBScript and I was making a message box when an idea struck me: Can I 'mix and match' the buttons in a MsgBox, as in, instead of having `vbYesNo`, can you have `vbYesCancelRetry` or something?

Comment: Nope, you can only use the predefined constants. (Although the argument is a bitmask you are only permitted one member from the button type enumeration range)

Answer (score 3):

> Can I 'mix and match' the buttons in a MsgBox, as in, instead of having `vbYesNo`, can you have `vbYesCancelRetry` or something?

This is easily answered by simply trying it out (hint: the answer is No).

The values MsgBox expects are [predefined constants](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa445082(v=vs.60).aspx):

```
Constant            Value    Binary
vbOKOnly            0        0000
vbOKCancel          1        0001
vbAbortRetryIgnore  2        0010
vbYesNoCancel       3        0011
vbYesNo             4        0100
vbRetryCancel       5        0101
```

Since the numbers are not all strict powers of two<sup>(*)</sup>, their binary representation overlaps. For example: `vbAbortRetryIgnore` shares a bit with `vbYesNoCancel`, but paints entirely different buttons.

The implication is: You can't switch on or off individual buttons, buttons only come in predefined sets. The constants are used to select one of the sets.

---

<sup>(*)</sup> If they were, they would each address an individual bit, resulting in such a pattern:

```
ButtonA    0    0000
ButtonB    1    0001
ButtonC    2    0010
ButtonD    4    0100
ButtonE    8    1000
```

Under such circumstances you could mix and match. Alas, that's not the way the [MessageBox API function](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms645505(v=vs.85).aspx) is implemented in Windows. VBScript's `MsgBox()` is just a thin wrapper around that system function call.